# Flink: all traffic goes to one Task Manager (in cluster with 1 Job Manager + 2 Task Managers)

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have following set up:

```
Installation type k8s: 1.18
Flink version: 1.12
1 Job Manager
2 Task Manager
```

In flink-conf.yaml of task manager

```
  flink-conf.yaml: |
    state.backend: rocksdb
    blob.server.port: 6124
    jobmanager.rpc.port: 6123
    parallelism.default: 2
    queryable-state.proxy.ports: 6125
    taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 2
    taskmanager.rpc.port: 6122
    jobmanager.memory.process.size: 2900m
    taskmanager.memory.process.size: 2900m
    jobmanager.web.address: 0.0.0.0
    rest.address: 0.0.0.0
    rest.bind-address: 0.0.0.0
```

In flink-conf.yaml of job manager

```
  flink-conf.yaml: |
    state.backend: rocksdb
    blob.server.port: 6124
    jobmanager.rpc.port: 6123
    parallelism.default: 2
    queryable-state.proxy.ports: 6125
    taskmanager.rpc.port: 6122
    jobmanager.memory.process.size: 2900m
    taskmanager.memory.process.size: 2900m
    jobmanager.web.address: 0.0.0.0
    rest.address: 0.0.0.0
    rest.bind-address: 0.0.0.0
    rest.port: 8081
```

With above configuration, only one task manager is active i.e. gets traffic and another task manager remains idle, even though number of events increases to extreme level.

Please suggest, if I am missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the parallelism to 2, and given each task manager 2 slots. Thus a single task manager can provide the requested parallelism, and that's what will happen by default.

If you want the scheduler to behave differently, you could set

```
cluster.evenly-spread-out-slots: true
```

or you could reduce `taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots` to 1.

Comment: After `taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots` to 1, it worked for me. Also it was some environment issue also. It was working on one of env and not working on another.